# tkinter- Photoimage Menubutton errors out

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried using a photoimage in menubutton of tkinter..

The program ran correctly..

BUT.

When i closed the window..

This error occured:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Image.__del__ at 0x028AF028>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\programming\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4018, in __del__
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

the code that has the error:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
toolbar = tk.Frame(root)

toolbar_menu_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = "./icon.png")
toolbar_menu = tk.Button(toolbar, image=toolbar_menu_icon)
toolbar_menu.pack()

toolbar.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

### THE ONLY WORKAROUND I CAN FIND:

I had to modify `__init__.py` from `PYTHON_PATH/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py`

and replace line 4018 with:

`except Exception:`

as before it was:

`except TclError`

this ensures that with any exception, this will work..

Comment: The error is most likely in the try-except block. Add code that other people can just copy from the question, run it and check what's wrong with it.

Comment: @8349697 what try-except? My program doesn't include and try-except statement..

Comment: In [this block](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L4014).

Comment: There are no errors in the code snippet supplied. Your problem seems to be class related.

Comment: The section of code you have posted does not raise any errors. Please provide a [mre] so we can see the problem.

Comment: Okay @Henry I will update it..

Comment: The error raised here is caused by the filename. If you modify code to include `from tkinter import filedialog as fido` then insert `imagename = fido.askopenfilename( title = 'Pick image' )` and use imagename instead. The code works!

Comment: @Derek isn't there any other way to do this?

Comment: If the problem isn't in the code sample you are supplying then it must be in some other part. Do you have a class or are you sub-classing anywhere else in your code? Modifying `tkinter` is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same old problem for me using Ubuntu 23.10, using its system Python 3.11.6 which has Tkinter 8.6. This problem appears to be an old error that the devs thought they had fixed in 2014:

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/62341

So the globals are destroyed in the wrong order according to that. Well, the window close-event is tied to root.destroy() not root.quit(), so associating it with root.quit() instead prevents the error message. Fixed.

Oh wait, that causes a new problem. If you're running Python in a Tkinter-based IDE like IDLE, then you find you can't close the window at all because IDLE is keeping Tkinter alive. So add more lines after the root.mainloop() to delete the Photoimage first, *then* destroy all the rest with root.destroy(). It's a lot of fuss to stop an error message, though.

So here's the code from the above question with those extra lines tacked on:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
toolbar_menu_icon = tk.PhotoImage(width=300,height=100)
toolbar_menu = tk.Button(toolbar, image=toolbar_menu_icon)
toolbar_menu.pack()
toolbar.pack()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.quit)
root.mainloop()
del toolbar_menu_icon
root.destroy()
```